# Unable to find web.xml in netbeans 7.0.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml, deployment-descriptor

I want to upload a file to a server, for which I am writing a servlet program.The location of the directory where the document would be uploaded should be fetched from a parameter in web.xml. I have not use web.xml before and only know that it makes entries for each servlet. I am not able to see this file in my web application project that i am making in netbeans. Please help me with this. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It should be located in `YOURPROJECT\web\WEB-INF` folder, so the full path will be: `YOURPROJECT\web\WEB-INF\web.xml`

---

**EDIT (Aug 21, 2015)**

Got a downvote with a comment from [duffymo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37213/duffymo), that my answer is not correct.

[image: comment]

And I decided to illustrate my answer with step-by-step pictures to avoid any misunderstanding.

I am going to illustrate Netbeans behaviour in Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows (Windows 7) operating systems.

**Linux:**

1. Let's create a simple Java Web project with default settings.

[image: simple web project on linux system]

2. We're going to the project folder to inspect the contents of this folder:

[image: web project folder on linux system]

**note, that `web` folder is there.**

3. Navigating further:

[image: contents of web folder on linux system]

[image: web.xml file location on linux system, file is not created yet]

You [can create a web.xml file in this folder manually](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1830/abxii/index.html) or do it using Netbeans via project context menu "New -> Create -> Other":

[image: creating web.xml on linux system in netbeans #1]

[image: creating web.xml on linux system in netbeans #2]

Now, we're navigating `YOURPROJECT\web\WEB-INF\` folder to see, that `web.xml` is there:

[image: created web.xml file]

The same rules are correct for windows operating system, check the pictures below:

[image: web-application project folder on windows]

[image: contents of web-application folder on windows]

You can create web.xml here:

[image: web.xml file location on windows]

or use Netbeans, as I described above.

Comment: Create web.xml in this folder by yourself. Here is the link to sample web.xml file: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1830/abxii/index.html

Comment: This is incorrect.  There's no /web in that path.  Should be context root with /WEB-INF directly underneath.

Comment: @duffymo I've updated my answer. As you can see, there is a `web` folder, as I advised to OP.

Comment: My point is that it's a Netbeans only convention.  The WAR file that results will have no such /web folder, just the context root.  I'll reverse my downvote.

Comment: @duffymo OP question was related to Netbeans IDE, so I provided guidelines for this particular IDE.

Comment: Agreed. I think it's important for people to understand what's going on underneath

Comment: THANKS YOU VERY MUCH FRIEND! YOU SAVED MY LIFE!

Answer (score 30):

I know it's so late but I had the same problem, so here's the solution below:

To create web.xml:

1. Right click on your project
2. Choose New
3. Choose Other
4. Box New file is opened, in Filter search web.xml
5. You will get the file you want web.xml, then click next...then finish

(Tested on Netbean 7.4 JDK 7)

Answer (score 6):

`web.xml` is optional in `Java EE 6`. So, by default it is not loaded in `Netbeans`. You need to manually load `web.xml` from Netbeans.

Comment: then how to add a context if i don't have web.xml

Comment: hmm, if it's optional, what's the alternative approach?

Answer (score 2):

You need to firstly create a servlet page then web.xml will be generated in WEB.INF/

Answer (score 2):

Try to right click the project and select `New` -> `Other`-> `Web` -> `Standard Deployment Descriptor (web.xml)` -> `Next` -> `Finish`. Follow that and it will be created in Configuration Files.

Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAMOeHtPwrc

Answer (score 0):

You could use context-parameters in your web.xml

In you normal java class you read this this static fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ...>
...
<context-param>
    <description>directory where the document would be uploaded</description>
    <param-name>directory</param-name>
    <param-value>/tmp</param-value>
</context-param>
...
</web-app>
```

And you can access this context parameter with `ServletContext.getInitParameter` function.

If you are using Servlet 3.0 specification you can use annotations(http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/package-summary.html).
I think that `@WebInitParam` is what are you looking for.

Comment: The problem is there is no web.xml in my WEB-INF

Comment: You have to open a text editor, create a new file named "web.xml", and add what's necessary.