# welcome file configuration alternative to web.xml

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, netbeans, web.xml

In the absence of `web.xml`, where is the welcome file configuration?

background:

> 10.10 Welcome Files
>
> Web Application developers can define an ordered list of partial URIs called welcome files in the Web application
>   deployment descriptor.
>
> Java Servlet Specification Version 3.0 Rev a December 2010

I'm using Netbeans 8 and didn't realize that `web.xml` duties are now largely done with annotations.  However, I can't seem to find an annotation relating to welcome files.  Currently, `index.html` loads, I'd like to reconfigure that to `foo.jsp`.  Can this be done without creating a `web.xml` file?

see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19317470/262852

update:

I added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>foo.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

as `web.xml` and it works fine -- but would like to accomplish the same result without `xml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Servlet 3.0, several new annotations are defined. These annotations are resided in the package [**javax.servlet.annotation**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/package-summary.html).

As you can see , There is no special **annotation** to define the **welcome-file** list ,also please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13450154/957654) .

but please check the following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11789328/957654) as it describes a workaround to get your welcome file reconfigure that to foo.jsp .

if you are on **tomcat** server, also check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17247947/957654).

Hope that helps